# Кастомные роли Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, архитектура

Всем привет. Есть приложение на Laravel, где есть 2 основные сущности: юзер и компания. Необходимо реализовать роли юзеров. Задача осложняется тем, что юзеры получают роли не для всего сайта, а локально для компаний.

Для глобальных ролей пользовался библиотекой [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/). В данном же случае она не подходит, поскольку в ней роли идут глобально. Подскажите, как правильнее поступить: кастомизировать данную библиотеку под меня или же написать все с нуля?

Answer (score 1):

Тоже нужно было сделать решение, много компаний и у каждой свои роли и права могут быть. Воспользовался данным плагином spatie/laravel-permission, пришлось немного допилить под себя. Там возникает проблема когда много ролей копиться в БД (у нас больше 3000), ответ от БД начинает тормозить. Если нужно будет, то могу подсказать что нужно подправить.
В остальном все отлично: посредники, проверки, синхронизация. Рекомендую!

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону пакета Laratrust: https://laratrust.readthedocs.io

Я когда-то использовал его для простого распределения ролей. Но там есть понятие teams. На первый взгляд, это то, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 0):

В ларавеле есть более-менее стандартный подход в виде возможности добавить собственные [политики безопасности](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#authorizing-actions-via-gates), внутри которых можно, например, проверить есть ли у пользователя права на работу с конкретными компаниями. Весь подход уложится в написание такой политики, создание связи Company-User, которая и будет задавать права на работу с конкретными компаниями. Если нужно распределение ролей — то в эту же таблицу со связью можно добавить поле с уровнем доступа и также его проверять в политике.